# How to delete the duplicate records from a table if it has a lot of columns in SQL (don't use col1...coln in query)?

Tags: sql

I need SQL query where it has col1...coln I want to remove the duplicates records by not using col1...coln in query.

```
#WITH CTE AS(
   #SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) FROM dbo.Table1)
#DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Here col1...col7 are used but if table has 1000 columns how we can write the SQL query in such scenario to remove duplicates records.

Comment: Don't tag 3 *completely* different RDBMS, it is not going to get your question more views, it is only going to confuse the people you are asking for help from when they don't know what dialect to answer in, and possibly attract downvotes. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any *magic* that is capable of doing it. It is you who know what makes those duplicates. If it is only one column, fine - you'll use that one. Otherwise, you'll have to name them all, regardless of their number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate total duplicates, you can use `select distinct *` and `truncate table`:

```
create table temp_t as
    select distinct *
    from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

Of course, before truncating a table stash it somewhere in case something goes wrong.

Note:  This only works on *all* columns.  If you care about a subset, then you need to list the columns specifically.